# Showing route in google maps in iphone

Tags: iphone, dictionary

I have to display path between multiple locations in map in which travelling salesman problem should be solved. i used google direction api but it can handle only 8 way points in reguler account .i have to display path between cities more than 8 ...should i make algorithem for that ?can anyone help in this

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Well for this you need to implement the Map Routes Methods. You can make it yourself but there are already classes made for this before. Please check :-

https://github.com/route-me/route-me

[Google Maps SDK for iOS and routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756762/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-and-routes)

[How to draw routes on maps in ios 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246702/how-to-draw-routes-on-maps-in-ios-6)

Hope this helps you otherwise please tell . I can provide you some classes